# Spaces in between text in a html button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following code below, in my jQuery append command, I have included 4 spaces in between the texts, but when I run the code, there's only one space in between the texts. How do I make the four spaces appear?

```js
jQuery("#column_3").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + "Test 1    Test 2    Test 3" + ' </button></div >');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="column_3">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try `&nbsp` x 4 in between Tests

Comment: Whitespace collapses in HTML; otherwise we wouldn't be able to format / indent code.  Use non-breaking spaces or css padding/margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a couple ways,

easiest is adding the `&nbsp;`

```js
jQuery("#column_3").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + 'Test 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test 3' + ' </button></div >');
```

```html
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="column_3">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also wrap the text in spans

```js
jQuery("#column_3").append('<div class="col-md-auto myHandle"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + '<span>Test 1</span><span>Test 1</span><span>Test 1</span>' + ' </button></div >');
```

```css
.myHandle span{margin-right:20px;}
```

```html
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="column_3">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I noticed that you're mixing opening and closing quotes in your jQuery (using `'` and `"` in the same string), best to avoid that.

Comment: Snippetify please

Answer (score 2):

Add `&nbsp;` for each space you would like. Normal spaces are collapsed in HTML.

```js
jQuery("#column_3").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + "Test 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Test 3" + ' </button></div >');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="column_3">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A  way not mentioned is using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with `pre` tags for formatting.

```js
jQuery("#column_3").append(`<div class=col-md-auto> <button type=button class=list-group-item><pre>Test 1    Test 2    Test 3   </pre></button></div >`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <div id="column_3">
          <div class="list-group-item"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simple spaces, that doesn't work as you expect, because HTML cuts it off, use this:
 `&nbps;`  
each `&nbsp;` refers to a single space.